# jquery validation plugin and inputmask plugin: validate against the mask?

Tags: jquery

I'm using these two jQuery plugins, one to apply a mask on the field, one to validate the field:

- jquery.inputmask: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask
- jQuery Validation Plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Is there a way to make the validation plugin validating the data based on the mask defined in the first plugin without rewritting validation rules?

Thanks